# shell job to compress & delete logs, once in a month

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cron, cron-task

I am trying to run a schedule job on centOS to .gz and delete a whole month of logs from a directory. The logs are named somelogfile_12Apr19_18_19_41.log, somelogfile_28Mar19_07_08_20.log

I can run the below script to manually do this task

```
tar -cvzf somezipfile_Mar19.tar.gz somelogfile_**Mar** --remove-files
```

The scheduled job should run every 5th day of the month to compress and delete the previous months logs. What will the automated script be like? I am stuck at how to include only the previous months logs based on the month name (Jan,Feb,Mar, etc.)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You should earch for "cron" - thats what you are searching for.

Comment: Think about using `-j` (bzip2) or `-J` (xz) instead of `-z` (gzip): xz compresses better than bzip2 and bzip2 better than gzip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem to solve is the fact that you want a more generic function that can be run any month and produce the correct result. A good tool to get the information you need(Abbreviated month and last two digits of the year) is `date`.

```
date -d "last month" +%b
```

When run on April 1st, 2019 will produce "Mar".

```
date -d "last month" +%b%y
```

When run on April 1st, 2019 will produce "Mar19".

Now that we know how to get the information we want, placing the `date` commands in the `tar` command will automatically produce what the result you're looking for.

```
tar -cvzf somezipfile_$(date -d "last month"%b%y).tar.gz somelogfile_**$(date -d "last month" +%b)** --remove-files
```

The last issue that exists is scheduling, which can be solved using `cron`. The below statement will run `/bin/foobar`, on the 5th day of every month when added to your crontab file. (`crontab -e` to edit your crontab file)

```
0 0 5 * * /bin/foobar
```

Combining everything together, you get:

```
0 0 5 * * /bin/tar -cvzf somezipfile_$(date -d "last month"\%b\%y).tar.gz somelogfile_**$(date -d "last month" +\%b)** --remove-files
```

*Don't forget to escape the %'s in the crontab*

Comment: Brilliant !! That's neat @Ghosy